# How many transformations does Drive Knight have?

Tags: one-punch-man

In the last chapter of the manga, Drive Knight transformed into

> a sort of motorcycle.

In a past chapter of the manga and episode of the anime IIRC, he transformed into a centaur. Does he have more transformations?  How many transformations does Drive Knight have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, he has more transformations.** From the wiki, Drive Knight has 6 [Tactical Transformations](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Drive_Knight#Physical_Abilities). These are:

- **Knight** (桂馬, Keima): Drive Knight shapes his lower body into that of a horse, giving him the appearance of a centaur.
- **Silver** (銀, Gin): Drive Knight forms a long sword.
- **Chariot** (香車, Kyōsha): Drive Knight transforms into a sleek motorbike.
- **Flying Chariot** (飛車, Hisha): Drive Knight transforms into a bulky compact projectile with four wings and forms rocket engines that propel him forward.
- **Bishop** (角, Kaku): Drive Knight transforms into a large humanoid robot with a crested helmet.
- **Gold** (金, Kin): Drive Knight adds a layer of armor to his body. His hair turns white and his armor flares between its plates.

All in all, he has a total of six transformations. The ones you saw were the Knight and Chariot transformations. As @AkiTanaka mentioned, these are named after [shogi pieces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shogi#Equipment).

Comment: The trivia part might also be relevant that these forms are from Shogi pieces ;)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. I only play chess so I kinda thought some of these were probably chess pieces (Bishop and the Knight). Thanks for the additional info.